# Simplistic (dumb) Card Fighter

Tags: c#, game, community-challenge, role-playing-game

I wanted to play with value types for [Simon's challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1608/23788); I came up with this quick-and-dirty, basic implementation of a card-fighting game:

I started with a value type to hold *assets* - I'd reuse that type for player status, card cost and card effects:

```
public struct Assets
{
    private readonly int _warriors;
    private readonly int _mages;
    private readonly int _kings;
    private readonly int _health;

    public int Warriors { get { return _warriors; } }
    public int Mages { get { return _mages; } }
    public int Kings { get { return _kings; } }
    public int Health { get { return _health; } }

    public Assets(int warriors = 0, int mages = 0, int kings = 0, int health = 0)
    {
        _warriors = warriors < 0 ? 0 : warriors;
        _mages = mages < 0 ? 0 : mages;
        _kings = kings < 0 ? 0 : kings;
        _health = health < 0 ? 0 : health;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a new Assets instance with warriors and mages incremented by the number of kings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Assets GetKingsBenediction()
    {
        return new Assets(warriors: _warriors + _kings,
                          mages: _mages + _kings,
                          kings: _kings,
                          health: _health);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Health: {0}\nWarriors: {1}\nMages: {2}\nKings: {3}", _health, _warriors, _mages, _kings);
    }
}
```

`CardEffect` is also a `struct`, and might act upon one or more of either the player's or his opponent's assets:

```
public struct CardEffect
{
    public static readonly int MaxEffect = 255;
    public static readonly Assets NoOp = new Assets();

    private readonly Assets _player;
    private readonly Assets _opponent;

    public Assets PlayerAssets { get { return _player; } }
    public Assets OpponentAssets { get { return _opponent; } }

    public CardEffect(Assets player, Assets opponent)
    {
        _player = player;
        _opponent = opponent;
    }
}
```

A `GameCard` is nothing more than a `Name`, a `Cost` and an `Effect` then:

```
public class GameCard
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly Assets _cost;
    private readonly CardEffect _effect;

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public Assets Cost { get { return _cost; } }
    public CardEffect Effect { get {return _effect;} }

    public GameCard(string name, Assets cost, CardEffect effect)
    {
        _name = name;
        _cost = cost;
        _effect = effect;
    }
}
```

Here's the `Game` class, showing the `GameCard` constructor in action:

```
public class Game
{
    public static readonly Assets StartAssets = new Assets(warriors: 5, mages: 3, kings: 1, health: 30);

    // todo: make non-static, implement deck & player hand
    public static IEnumerable<GameCard> _cards = new[] 
    {
        new GameCard("Attack", new Assets(warriors: 3), new CardEffect(CardEffect.NoOp, new Assets(health: 5))),
        new GameCard("Recruit", new Assets(mages: 2), new CardEffect(new Assets(warriors: 5), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("Panic Kingdom", new Assets(kings: 1), new CardEffect(new Assets(warriors: 10, mages: 10), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("Pick a King, Any King", new Assets(warriors: 6, mages: 6), new CardEffect(new Assets(kings: 1), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("Heal Me", new Assets(mages: 2), new CardEffect(new Assets(health: 4), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("All-In!", new Assets(warriors: 10), new CardEffect(CardEffect.NoOp, new Assets(health: 15))),
        new GameCard("Mega Heal", new Assets(mages: 5), new CardEffect(new Assets(health: 11), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("Transforming", new Assets(warriors: 2), new CardEffect(new Assets(mages: 2), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("Wizards in the City", new Assets(warriors: 2), new CardEffect(new Assets(mages: 4), CardEffect.NoOp)),
        new GameCard("Slay Kingdom", new Assets(warriors: 7, mages: 7), new CardEffect(CardEffect.NoOp, new Assets(warriors: CardEffect.MaxEffect,mages: CardEffect.MaxEffect)))
    };

    public void Run(IEnumerable<PlayerBase> players)
    {
        while (players.Count(p => !p.IsDead) > 1)
        {
            foreach (var player in players)
            {
                if (!player.IsDead)
                {
                    player.Play(players);
                }

                if (!player.IsDead && players.Count(p => !p.IsDead) == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} wins!", player.Name);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I've coded lots of logic inside the `PlayerBase` abstract class, but the *hand* isn't done at this point - I just made `Game._cards` `public static` so I could have a bunch of cards to play with:

```
public abstract class PlayerBase
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private Assets _assets;

    protected PlayerBase(string name, Assets assets)
    {
        _name = name;
        _assets = assets;
    }

    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public Assets Assets { get { return _assets; } set { _assets = value; IsDead = _assets.Health == 0; } }

    public bool IsDead { get; private set; }

    public void Play(IEnumerable<PlayerBase> players)
    {
        // todo: draw a card
        _assets = _assets.GetKingsBenediction();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} assets:", Name);
        Console.WriteLine(_assets);

        // todo: implement hand
        var hand = Game._cards; // public static - todo: make private, non-static

        var card = PickCard(hand);
        if (PayCardCost(card))
        {
            var opponent = PickOpponent(card, players.Where(player => !player.Equals(this)));
            PlayCard(card, opponent);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decide which on-hand card to play.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract GameCard PickCard(IEnumerable<GameCard> hand);

    protected abstract PlayerBase PickOpponent(GameCard card, IEnumerable<PlayerBase> opponents);

    private bool PayCardCost(GameCard card)
    {
        if (_assets.Warriors - card.Cost.Warriors >= 0
         && _assets.Mages - card.Cost.Mages >= 0
         && _assets.Kings - card.Cost.Kings >= 0
         && _assets.Health - card.Cost.Health >= 0)
        {
            _assets = new Assets(warriors: _assets.Warriors - card.Cost.Warriors,
                                 mages: _assets.Mages - card.Cost.Mages,
                                 kings: _assets.Kings - card.Cost.Kings,
                                 health: _assets.Health - card.Cost.Health);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void PlayCard(GameCard card, PlayerBase opponent)
    {
        if (!card.Effect.PlayerAssets.Equals(CardEffect.NoOp))
        {
            _assets = new Assets(
                        warriors: _assets.Warriors + card.Effect.PlayerAssets.Warriors,
                        mages: _assets.Mages + card.Effect.PlayerAssets.Mages,
                        kings: _assets.Kings + card.Effect.PlayerAssets.Kings,
                        health: _assets.Health + card.Effect.PlayerAssets.Health);
        }

        if (!card.Effect.OpponentAssets.Equals(CardEffect.NoOp))
        {
            opponent.Assets = new Assets(
                            warriors: opponent.Assets.Warriors - card.Effect.OpponentAssets.Warriors,
                            mages: opponent.Assets.Mages - card.Effect.OpponentAssets.Mages,
                            kings: opponent.Assets.Kings - card.Effect.OpponentAssets.Kings,
                            health: opponent.Assets.Health - card.Effect.OpponentAssets.Health);
        }
    }
```

---

The `ConsolePlayer` being used merely picks the first card in the "hand", and always picks the first opponent - as a result the two players fight each others to death using nothing other than "Attack" cards, but that's enough to say that, except for the "hand", everything works:

**Output:**

> ```
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 30
> Warriors: 6
> Mages: 4
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 25
> Warriors: 6
> Mages: 4
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 25
> Warriors: 4
> Mages: 5
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 20
> Warriors: 4
> Mages: 5
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 20
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 6
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 20
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 6
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 20
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 7
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 15
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 7
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 15
> Warriors: 1
> Mages: 8
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 15
> Warriors: 1
> Mages: 8
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 15
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 9
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 15
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 9
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 15
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 10
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 10
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 10
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 10
> Warriors: 1
> Mages: 11
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 10
> Warriors: 1
> Mages: 11
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 10
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 12
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 10
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 12
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 10
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 13
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 5
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 13
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 5
> Warriors: 1
> Mages: 14
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 5
> Warriors: 1
> Mages: 14
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 5
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 15
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player2 assets:
> Health: 5
> Warriors: 2
> Mages: 15
> Kings: 1
> Player2 plays Attack.
> Cannot play that card. Skipping turn.
> Player1 assets:
> Health: 5
> Warriors: 3
> Mages: 16
> Kings: 1
> Player1 plays Attack.
> Player1 wins!
> ```

`public static` stuff *that works around the absence of a deck and of a hand* aside, **is everything where it belongs**? I don't code `struct`s very often, guts tell me I've stuffed too much logic in `Assets`... I don't like that I have tied `PlayerBase` to the `Console`, would it be cleaner to have `Game` listen for player events and write to console accordingly?

Comment: `IsDead` should be calculated dynamically. No setter. It should be determined solely on internal state. You can ask me if I'm dead, but you can't tell me.

Comment: @radarbob very good point, thanks! `public bool IsDead { get { return _assets.Health == 0; } }` ...and that fixes the annoying `IsDead` assignation in the setter for `Assets`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this:

```
 if (_assets.Warriors - card.Cost.Warriors >= 0
     && _assets.Mages - card.Cost.Mages >= 0
     && _assets.Kings - card.Cost.Kings >= 0
     && _assets.Health - card.Cost.Health >= 0)
```

Has no business in the `PlayerBase` class. In as much as `GameCard` contains both of these objects, this logic should be there as well. And of course it needs to be encapsulated w/ descriptive name.

### Edit

Explore the idea of having `Asset` implement `IComparable`, **then the above is the meat of `CompareTo()`**. Then `GameCard` can also implement `IComparable` and can call `Asset.CompareTo` it it's own implementation. Easy Peasy.

### End Edit

**Fractal OO**

Go deep w/ abstraction/encapsulation. For example:

```
 public void Run(IEnumerable<PlayerBase> players)
{
    while (players.Count(p => !p.IsDead) > 1)
    {
       //redacted
            if (!player.IsDead && players.Count(p => !p.IsDead) == 1)
            { // redacted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

could read more abstractly:

```
public void Run(IEnumerable<PlayerBase> players)
{
    while (CombatStillPossible)
    {
       //redacted
            if (LastPlayerStanding)
            { // redacted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Run()` is fuzzy**

Looking at the original code as just the method parameters together w/ the overall control logic, it is not at all clear what I'm seeing. Also, the seeming nested-repeated logic is making me wonder about flawed logic or poorly structured logic.

I wonder if you get the outlier conditions out of the way first thing then all the logic is clearer.

```
 public void Run(IEnumerable<PlayerBase> players)
{
    if(NoLivingPlayers) { etc, etc, return;}  // covers a null argument too
    if(OnePlayerAlive) { // we have a winner, return;} // covers the case of a collection of 1 player

    while (CombatStillPossible)
    {
        // internal logic would have avoided the "3 players bug"
        // internal logic keeps paring players and fighting each pair
        // until only one is left.

        Tournament meatGrinder = new Tournament(); // pass in all the players
        PlayerBase winner = meatGrinder.Fight();

        // a null winner means everyone is dead
        // "winner" could be class variable so it can be evaluated in
        // NoLivingPlayers, etc.

        if(NoLivingPlayers) {// oh well, etc.; continue;}
        if (LastPlayerStanding)
        { // winner, etc.;}
    }
}
```

Sure, the above is putting off actually doing anything, but we're going fractal here. `Tournament` will internally pair players...

```
public class Combatants {
    public PlayerBase Player1 { get; protected set; }
    public PlayerBase Player2 { get; protected set; }

    public Combatants(PlayerBase player1, PlayerBase player2) {

    }

    public PlayerBase Fight() {} // here is the logic of single combat.
}
```

**What We Have**

1. The game *driving* the tournament
2. The Tournament *driving* the pairing of combatants
3. The Combatants *doing* the fighting.
4. Better separation of concerns
5. We coded at appropriate levels of abstraction w/in each class. A.K.A. we pushed details down.
6. **[edit]** One more thing.... the `while` may now seen superfluous, but it got me to thinking that `Tournament` can now be passed as a parameter and now we can have game variations. Holy Inversion of Control, Batman.

Comment: Is there a link for the "fractal oo" terminology?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca, I just ran across that phrase one day somewhere on StackExchange. It just was very insightful.  "Object oriented principles are fractal." - a fractal is a "self-similar pattern." In other words as you go deeper into code, OO principles - the patterns, if you will - should be there.

Answer (score 4):

Not going to review this code just yet, but I've found a funny bug, by adding a 3rd player:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var game = new Game();
    var players = new[] 
            { 
                new ConsolePlayer("Player1", Game.StartAssets), 
                new ConsolePlayer("Player2", Game.StartAssets),
                new ConsolePlayer("Player3", Game.StartAssets)
            };

    game.Run(players);
}
```

This would run an infinite loop, and eventually hit an overflow exception when players have more mages and warriors than C# can count.

The bug is on this line:

```
var opponent = PickOpponent(card, players.Where(player => !player.Equals(this)));
```

`PickOpponent` gets to fight a dead player!

This fixes is:

```
var opponent = PickOpponent(card, players.Where(player => !player.IsDead && !player.Equals(this)));
```

---

I don't like that `PickOpponent` is provided with "opponents" - it should take "players", and determine itself what players are possible opponents.